# When to put URLs for resources in REST responses?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have seen some web services respond with a link to another resource instead of inlining the resource data in the resource requested. When is this approach preferred? Or am I fine using only JSON for instance in my response? Without creating links to other resources...

```
{
    ...
    user: "api/user/6"
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

URLs provided in the REST response body or the headers are generally reference URLs. Suppose you are creating an entity by calling a REST service and you want to know how to retrieve that entity details later. So when entities are generally created, they are associated with a unique id. This Id is generally used in the reference URLs to get that entity. Here is the example:

```
CREATE

    /api/entity/ : POST to create an entity

RESPONSE : 200 OK response body/header
/api/entity/1
```

where 1 is the id generated for that entity so now you can do a GET to retrieve the complete details of the newly created entity

```
GET : /api/entity/1
RESPONSE: details of the entity.
```

Comment: So you Always use json, xml etc in the actjal response? You dont use links there?

Comment: What do you mean by links here? We are talking about the REST APIs and not the webpage

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on @Juned  Ahsan answer,
In most cases the response code for POST action on a REST service should be **201 Created**.
In that case, according to [HTTP 1.1 protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> The newly created resource can be referenced by the URI(s) returned in the entity of the response, with the most specific URI for the resource given by a Location header field.